# What is the name of row click event in ag-grid-react reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

If a user click or select a row in ag-grid  then I want to fire a click event. I searched the doc but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

It's called `onRowClicked` and `onRowSelected` respectively. `onRowClicked` will be called when you click a row even if you disable row selection. `onRowSelected` on the other hand only fires when a row is selected

```js
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  onRowSelected={(e) => console.log("row selected", e.rowIndex)}
  onRowClicked={(e) => console.log("row clicked", e.rowIndex)}
  rowSelection="multiple"
  rowData={rowData}
/>
```

Another way is to catch all of the ag-grid events using `GridApi.addGlobalListener()` and filter out the ones you're not interested in.

```js
const onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
  params.api.addGlobalListener((type: string, e) => {
    if (type === "rowClicked" || type === "rowSelected") {
      console.log(type, "from global event handler");
    }
  });
};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit smoosh-hill-evpq3]

Answer (score 0):

we are using onRowClicked property to get row data value

```
const rowDataSelection = useCallback(value => {
    setRowData({rowData: value.data || {}})
})

<Grid
    onRowClicked={rowDataSelection}
/>
```